# Generate following subsets from list in efficient/pythonic manner

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

From the list `[1,2,3,4]` I would like to get `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]`. I'm not sure what this is called (if anything), perhaps something like *following subsets*?

My current approach is:

```
def following_subsets(parts):
    following_subsets = []
    for i in range(1, len(parts)):
        following_subsets.append(parts[:-i])
    return following_subsets
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, or a more pythonic way? Perhaps utilising iterators in some fashion?

Comment: you could make it a list comprehension ... but other than being a more pythonc one liner there isnt much benifit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> [l[:i+1] for i in range(len(l))]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```